# Dimesions must be equal keras model

Tags: python, keras

Hey I am just starting to learn neural networks and I am trying to train my model but I think that the error is with what I chose as my loss function. The model is trying to predict two numbers of how many people will use a service. Here is the model I am trying to run

```
dat = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/byui- 
cse/cse450-course/master/data/bikes.csv')


dat['dteday'] = pd.to_datetime(dat['dteday'])
dat['dteday'] = dat['dteday'].values.astype('float64')

for col in dat.columns:
    dat[col] = dat[col].astype(np.float64)

dat_features = dat.copy()

dat_labels = dat_features.drop(columns = ['casual', 'registered'])
dat_labels.info()
dat_features = np.array(dat_features)
dat_features

bike_model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
layers.Dense(10),
# layers.Dense(20),
layers.Dense(2)
])

bike_model1.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())


bike_model1.fit(dat_features, dat_labels, epochs=10)
```

the error I am getting is this:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 10 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_3/dense_8/BiasAdd, Cast)' with input shapes: [?,2], [?,10]
```

Comment: The code so far runs fine, please provide a minimal reproducible sample.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error when compiling or when fitting?

If fitting, than what is the shape of your true labels? Your model output has shape (?,2), if your true values have other shape, it can create a problem.

I didn't understand from the code what are you trying to predict, but if you are providing your dat_labels to the model as true labels, than it's exactly what you should get as an error: dat_labels has a shape of (?,10), whereas the output of the model has shape of (?,2), you cannot compare the vector of the size 2 with the vector of the size 10.

Comment: it is trying to predict the number people that will use the service and whether they are registered or just causal based off of 10 features, so we would want that as an output.

the model crashes when fitting but I am not sure what the shape is of my true labels or if I am even using true labels, as far as I know it should just be passing numbers and spitting out a number for what I am trying to predict.  when I change the output layer to 1 my loss becomes nan so I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: If you show how you fit it may help to answer your question. From your description I guess that your target should be a dataframe with the columns ['casual', 'registered'], but I don't see where you create it